# Longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres Base-64

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, datatables, encriptación

Intento desencriptar los datos encriptados de un `DataTable` con la siguiente función.

```
for (int a = 0; a < dataTable.Columns.Count; a++)
{
    if (dataTable.Columns[a].DataType != typeof(String)) continue;
    for (int b = 0; b < dataTable.Rows.Count; b++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows[b][a] = SecurityProtocol.DecryptString(dataTable.Rows[b][a].ToString());
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
|      Valor Inicial     |             Encriptado           |     Desencriptado      |
|------------------------|----------------------------------|------------------------|
|"ITSC"                  |"aREOeLQEHW0="                    |"ITSC"                  |
|"Desarrollo de software"|"t28FXWcQswHA5FzQq2y8Uc3CMvdQpnQ2"|"Desarrollo de software"|
|"Técnico superior"      |"Z9PFyFnDukGzYXs"                 |   >>>> Error <<<<      |
```

Pero recibo un error cuando intenta desencriptar la columna `"Type"`:
**Longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres Base-64.**

Probé la función con `string` pero no ocurrió ningún error.

```
    public void DecryptStringTest()
    {
        string encriptado1 = SecurityProtocol.EncriptString("ITSC");
        string encriptado2 = SecurityProtocol.EncriptString("Desarrollo de software");
        string encriptado3 = SecurityProtocol.EncriptString("Técnico superior");

        Console.WriteLine(SecurityProtocol.DecryptString(encriptado1));
        Console.WriteLine(SecurityProtocol.DecryptString(encriptado2));
        Console.WriteLine(SecurityProtocol.DecryptString(encriptado3));            
    }
```

**Salida:**

```
|      Valor Inicial     |             Encriptado           |     Desencriptado      |
|------------------------|----------------------------------|------------------------|
|"ITSC"                  |"aREOeLQEHW0="                    |"ITSC"                  |
|"Desarrollo de software"|"t28FXWcQswHA5FzQq2y8Uc3CMvdQpnQ2"|"Desarrollo de software"|
|"Técnico superior"      |"Z9PFyFnDukGzYXs"                 |"Técnico superior"      |
```

Código de función `DecryptString(string toDecrypt)`.

```
public static string DecryptString(string toDecrypt)
{
    //Error con DataRow["Type"].ToString() // Value = "Z9PFyFnDukGzYXs"
    //Longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres Base-64
    byte[] stringInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
    byte[] resoult = SecurityProtocol.DecryptTripleDES(stringInBytes);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resoult);
}
```

No tengo idea a que se debe el problema. Si fuera por el string me daría el mismo error con la prueba que hice, pero solo pasa con el DataTable. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: a `Z9PFyFnDukGzYXs` le falta un caracter o padding `"Z9PFyFnDukGzYXs=" 
` desencripta bien o sale cualquier cosa?

Comment: Cuando lo convierto a base-64 utilizando un string no me da ningun error.

Comment: "Longitud no válida" es que no es múltiplo de 4 como marca la respuesta, (en esa cadena hay 15) sin tener la clave no sabemos si te falta una letra o un `=` al final, que longitud tiene `DataRow["Type"]` ? yo descartaría que le falte un padding pues el primer caso lo incluye

Comment: cuando utilizo el string tiene la misma longitud  no me da ningun error.

Comment: Es una muy mala idea mostrar las cosas desencriptadas...

Comment: Me di cuenta de que la columna es un `varchar (15)` el error era que el string encriptado era más largo. Para el futuro intentaré usar `varchar (max)`.

Comment: @fredyfx. Le cambiaré el key.

Comment: Exacto, como te mencioné en la respuesta "Como ves hiciste una prueba con variables String lo que significa que el problema debe ser la cadena en la base de datos cambia el limite de los campos". Creo que ya puedes marcarla como respuesta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Base-64** cuenta con caracteres de relleno como ves en tu primer resultado encriptado al final tiene el caracter *=* pues es lo que te falta en el ultimo dato encriptado.

Posible causa:

Tu base de dato podría esta truncando caracteres revisa el tamaño del campo.

Para saber si hace falta un caracter de relleno o se cortó la cadena debes hacer lo siguiente.

```
if (encriptado.Length % 4 > 0);
```

Si se cumple esa condición tu cadena encriptada está mal o tan solo le falta el carácter de relleno.

Como ves hiciste una prueba con variables String lo que significa que el problema debe ser la cadena en la base de datos cambia el limite de los campos.

Es recomendable no poner limite a los campos en la base de datos ya que no sabremos cual será la longitud de nuestra cadena encriptada además un varchar(10) ocupa lo mismo que un varchar(max).

Ejemplo si quieren reparar la cadena:

`String a="YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3U" ;`

```
int b= a.length%4;

if(b!=0){

  for(int i=0; i < b; i++){
    a+="=";
  }

}
```

Aquí dejo esta documentación para que comprenda como se maneja **Base-64**: [Base-64](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Es que en el segundo no tiene el carácter = y no pasa el error y cuando uso el string se encripta de la misma forma que esta en la base de datos no se si el error tiene algo que ver con el dataTable.

Comment: No tiene relleno porque el es divisible completo de 4

Comment: Si le haces (encriptado3.length % 4) de seguro te dara un numero diferente a 0, lo que esta mal.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo

Comment: La condición se cumple con el segundo dato y ese no me da ningun error. Ademas no veo que eso pueda resolver el problema ya que dije que el error no ocurre cuando lo utilizo un string, teniendo en cuenta que el string tiene los mismos datos que el dataTable.

Comment: mi objetivo es desencriptar los datos con tu respuesta lo unico que hago es evitar el error.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(SecurityProtocol.DecryptString("Z9PFyFnDukGzYXs="));        pon esto y si te imprime "Técnico superior" mi respuesta es correcta

Comment: @JesseR.Jose no es este el caso pero hay ciertos mecanismos que descartan los paddings o los transforman en caracteres no válidos dentro del espacio base64, el ejemplo mas común es cuando se urlencodea (y uno no maneja esa parte, por ejemplo al usar ciertos servicios de shorturl)